# Failed to update the following work item error while tfs check-in

Tags: tfs

I have modified the tfs bug work item template as below so that while resolving a bug from active to resolved state root cause field is not empty.

AS Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin action is defined user can checkin in team explorer marking the work item as resolved.This cause error

Failed to update the following work item:
ID 39169. Reason: TF237124: Work Item is not ready to save

How can i allow user to update the root cause field while check-in from team explorer pend changes window

```
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Resolved">
    <REASONS>
       ....
    </REASONS>
    <FIELDS>
       ....
    <FIELD refname="RootCause">
    <REQUIRED />
    </FIELD>
    </FIELDS>
    <ACTIONS>
    <ACTION value="Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin" />
    </ACTIONS>
    </TRANSITION>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to update additional fields when you are associating work items with a checkin. I would recommend that you head over to http://visualstudio.uservoice.com and suggest that.

With your template above your developers would need to open and update the work item before the association to make it valid.

note: Your are also disabling Gated Checkin with this configuration.